# How to add Items in ComboBox on the selection of Items in the other ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

```
  <Grid>     
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="combo">
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="item1" Content="Mango"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="item2" Content="Apple"></ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="item3" Content="Tiger"></ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <ComboBox>
                    <ComboBox.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, ElementName=item1}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.Add" Value="Fruit"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ComboBox.Style>
                </ComboBox>          
             </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

In XAML I have two `ComboBoxes`.

If I select Item1 in ComboBox1 then some items should be added in ComboBox2.(i.e) ComboBox1 has Items such as Mango,Apple and Tiger.

On selecting Mango in the ComboBox1, item such as Fruit,Animal should be added to the ComboBox2 automatically.

Can anyone suggest me XAML code for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: SO is not a ready made code service,please show us your code attempt so we could help

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Since you are working with some kind of data, your logic belongs to the ViewModel and **not** to XAML. There is so much wrong stuff in your example. Please rewrite/overthink your question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in XAML alone.

Bind 2nd combobox itemssource to some enumerable and add current selected item of 1st combobox to the enumerable when selection changes on 1st combobox. Simple as that.